# Error starting executable built by a Go compiler

Tags: linux, go, coreos

I am new to Go, and I have a docker plugin written in Go on my MAC. I build it with the following command:

```
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

The output is binary file. When I copy it to CoreOS and try to execute:

```
./my-binary-file
```

the result is:

> "2016/12/07 08:05:00 Error Group root not found"

The OS on which file is executed is CoreOS. I've checked MAC and CoreOS, both of them are x86_64.

Why then I get this error?

**EDIT:**

The problem was in `ServerUnixGroup`. It should be "docker" instead of "root".

Comment: The output message looks as if it was formatted by log package, so it means the binary is running correctly. It is an application issue then.

Comment: Does the application have any dependencies ? Config Files, Environment Variables, etc.

Comment: Well, I am following this tutorial: 
https://blog.codeship.com/extend-docker-via-plugin/
So I am expecting after execution of binary to have a socket in ls -la /run/docker/plugins , but it is not there

I've changed "Mount" and "Unmount" methods in order to compile it and added Capabilities method as well.

Comment: Maybe it is something like this: 
https://github.com/docker/go-plugins-helpers/issues/38
I will check

Comment: Post your edit as an answer, and accept it -- this is a normal (and recommended) SO practice.

Comment: A nitpick: the invocation `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build` should work just fine without `env`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in `ServerUnixGroup`. It should be "docker" instead of "root".

– user2739823